# Understanding output of util.inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js

A RESTFul API's method I'm calling from node gives me the following XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableausoftware.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableausoftware.com/api http://tableausoftware.com/api/ts-api-2.0.xsd">
  <credentials token="xyzzy">
    <site contentUrl=""/>
  </credentials>
</tsResponse>
```

My ultimate goal is to grab the value of the **token** attribute associated with the **credentials** element and assign it to a variable in "my first node app".

My first stab at this involved using a module called xml2js. I'm able to convert the response above to a JS object, but then I had a hell of a time making sense of what I was left with.

I managed to accomplish my goal, but I really don't understand how I got there...it was pure trial and error on my part, really:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
...
parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                    console.log(util.inspect(result, false, 7));
                    tokencontainer = (result.tsResponse.credentials);
                    token = tokencontainer[0].$.token;
                });
```

The output of util.inspect is as follows:

```
{ tsResponse: 
   { '$': 
      { xmlns: 'http://tableausoftware.com/api',
        'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        'xsi:schemaLocation': 'http://tableausoftware.com/api http://tableausoftware.com/api/ts-api-2.0.xsd' },
     credentials: 
      [ { '$': { token: 'xyzzy' },
          site: [ { '$': { contentUrl: '' } } ] } ] } }
```

Can someone explain to me what this actually means? Even though I'm just playing with this for kicks, I want to understand what I'm looking at. For example:

- How would I reference the **xsi:schemalocation property** (or is it a
  key?) in JS?
- I'm sure I could reference the token value in a more
  concise fashion than I managed. How?
- What are those dollar signs there for? What do they signify?

...and of course, if there's a better way to approach this than using xml2js, I'm all ears. However I still want to understand what's going on above since it's new to me...

Thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would access `xsi:schemalocation` as `result.tsResponse.$['xsi:schemalocation']`.

Here's the basics of JavaScript object literal syntax. An object literal like

```
x = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6
}
```

has two properties, `x.a` (which is 5) and `x.b` (which is 6). Properties can themselves be objects:

```
outerObject = {
    innerObject: {a: 5}
}
```

Then `outerObject.innerObject.a` is 5.

Square brackets indicate arrays:

```
object = {
    includedArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

`object.includedArray[1]` is 'b'.

Property names can be written with quotes or without, so `{'a': 5}` and `{a: 5}` are the same. If the name is not a valid JavaScript identifier, you need to include the quotes. Properties can be accessed as either `obj.propertyName` or `obj['propertyName']`, but if the property name is not a JS identifier, you have to use the latter.

So, all together: `result.tsResponse.$['xsi:schemalocation']` - first we go down into the `tsResponse` object, then down into the `$` object (surprisingly, `$` is a valid JS identifier), and get the `xsi:schemalocation` property (`xsi:schemalocation` is not a valid identifier, because of the colon).

You might find the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2))` easier to read than `util.inspect`.

You could also get to the token as `result.tsResponse.credentials[0].$.token`, which is basically as what you wrote, without the temporary variable. Unfortunately you can't get much better than this with just xml2js.

About xml2js:

- xml2js uses the "$" property name to indicate the XML attributes, so
  `<element attr1="a" attr2="b">` will turn into something including `$: {attr1: 'a', attr2: 'b'}`. They could have chosen any other name, but they chose $ because it's an invalid XML element name (guaranteeing no clashes), and it's quick to type.
- By default, xml2js puts nested objects into an array. Example:

`<element>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <b>7</b>
    </element>`

becomes `{a: ['5', '6'], b: ['7']}`. Notice that `b` became an array as well, even though there's only one of them. If you check the xml2js documentation, you'll find an option to exclude the array when there's only one of them, so you'd get `{a: ['5', '6'], b: '7'}`, which is sometimes simpler to handle and sometimes more complicated.